# UserForm Include TextBox and/or ComboBox Values in strbody if certain conditions are met

Tags: vba, ms-word, combobox, userform

Below you will see several TextBox and ComboBox Values.

In another section of the code ComboBox6 has items "1", "2", and "3".

If ComboBox 6 Value is "1" I want string to Skip to not include this rows:
& " [" & ComboBox6.Value & "] " & TextBox9.Value _
& " [" & ComboBox7.Value & "] " & TextBox10.Value _

If ComboBox 6 Value is "2" I want the string not include this row:
& " [" & ComboBox7.Value & "] " & TextBox10.Value _

If ComboBox 6 Value is "3" then the code can include everything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

*** I am a complete novice. ***

I have the code below, but I don't know how to modify it to do what I need.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   ' Unload Me '(Closes your form and removes everything associated with it from memory)
    
    ' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'    Set OutMail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:13pt;font-family:Arial>" _
              & "<b><u>" & Label1 & "</u></b>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label5 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox3.Value & "</span>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label6 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox4.Value & "</span>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label7 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox3.Value & "</span>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label8 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox5.Value & "</span>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label9 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox6.Value & "</span>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label10 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox7.Value & "</span>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label11 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox8.Value & "</span>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label12 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox4.Value & "</span>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label13 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" _ 
              & " [" & ComboBox6.Value & "] " & TextBox9.Value _
              & " [" & ComboBox7.Value & "] " & TextBox10.Value _
              & " [" & ComboBox8.Value & "] " & TextBox11.Value & "</span>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label14 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox9.Value & TextBox12.Value & "</span>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label16 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox13.Value & "</span>"

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Case: " & TextBox3.Value & "; " & Label1
        .HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
        .Display
'        .Send
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but something like this would be shorter:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String, cbVal As Long, str As String
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    cbVal = CLng(Me.ComboBox5.Value) 'convert to number
    
    'add items according to value (assumes can only be 1,2 or 3)
    str = " [" & ComboBox6.Value & "] " & TextBox9.Value
    If cbVal > 1 Then str = str & " [" & ComboBox7.Value & "] " & TextBox10.Value
    If cbVal > 2 Then str = str & " [" & ComboBox8.Value & "] " & TextBox11.Value
    
    strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:13pt;font-family:Arial>" _
              & "<b><u>" & Label1 & "</u></b>" _
              & "<br><br>" & Label5 & GetSpan(TextBox3.Value) _
              & "<br><br>" & Label6 & GetSpan(TextBox4.Valu) _
              & "<br><br>" & Label7 & GetSpan(ComboBox3.Value) _
              & "<br><br>" & Label8 & GetSpan(TextBox5.Value) _
              & "<br><br>" & Label9 & GetSpan(TextBox6.Value) _
              & "<br><br>" & Label10 & GetSpan(TextBox7.Value) _
              & "<br><br>" & Label11 & GetSpan(TextBox8.Value) _
              & "<br><br>" & Label12 & GetSpan(ComboBox4.Value) _
              & "<br><br>" & Label13 & GetSpan(str) _
              & "<br><br>" & Label14 & GetSpan(ComboBox9.Value & TextBox12.Value) _
              & "<br><br>" & Label16 & GetSpan(TextBox13.Value)
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Case: " & TextBox3.Value & "; " & Label1
        .HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
        .Display
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

'return a string wrapping `v` in <span></span> with some styling
Function GetSpan(v) As String
    GetSpan = "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & v & "</span>"
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, the code is way shorter.  

The code did give a Compile Error: and it highlights the work **Str =** 

But I'm sure it's just a small detail.

I'll see if I can figure it out.

Thank you.

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZlY5.png

Comment: Added the following line and it worked. [Dim Str As String] Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If this was useful please mark as accepted by clicking the check mark - this helps anyone coming along later to see there's an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might have figured it out.
I basically did three If Then statements and copied/modified the codes as needed.
It's probably messy and lengthy, but that's how it turned out and it seems to work.
If anyone sees any issues, please let me know.

Thank you.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

If Me.ComboBox5.Value = "1" Then

strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:13pt;font-family:Arial>" _
          & "<b><u>" & Label1 & "</u></b>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label5 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox3.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label6 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox4.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label7 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox3.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label8 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox5.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label9 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox6.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label10 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox7.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label11 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox8.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label12 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox4.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label13 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & " [" & ComboBox6.Value & "] " & TextBox9.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label14 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox9.Value & TextBox12.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label16 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox13.Value & "</span>"

Else
End If

If Me.ComboBox5.Value = "2" Then

strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:13pt;font-family:Arial>" _
          & "<b><u>" & Label1 & "</u></b>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label5 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox3.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label6 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox4.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label7 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox3.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label8 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox5.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label9 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox6.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label10 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox7.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label11 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox8.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label12 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox4.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label13 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & " [" & ComboBox6.Value & "] " & TextBox9.Value _
                                                                                        & " [" & ComboBox7.Value & "] " & TextBox10.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label14 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox9.Value & TextBox12.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label16 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox13.Value & "</span>"

Else
End If

If Me.ComboBox5.Value = "3" Then

strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:13pt;font-family:Arial>" _
          & "<b><u>" & Label1 & "</u></b>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label5 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox3.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label6 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox4.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label7 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox3.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label8 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox5.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label9 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox6.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label10 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox7.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label11 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox8.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label12 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox4.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label13 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & " [" & ComboBox6.Value & "] " & TextBox9.Value _
                                                                                        & " [" & ComboBox7.Value & "] " & TextBox10.Value _
                                                                                        & " [" & ComboBox8.Value & "] " & TextBox11.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label14 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & ComboBox9.Value & TextBox12.Value & "</span>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Label16 & "<span style='background-color:rgb(192, 192, 192)'>" & TextBox13.Value & "</span>"

End If

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Case: " & TextBox3.Value & "; " & Label1
    .HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
    .Display
End With

On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

End Sub